# How to treat in Next.js "body >" sort of css selectors, which expects 'content' right under body?

Tags: next.js

Normally Next.js put a `<div id="__next">` inbetween `<body>` and the "content".

[image]

I would use this template: http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/

It has selectors, like: `body > nav .menu-brand`

What can I do to move `<nav>` right under `<body>`? If it is not there, part of skin.css will be not applied.

I would not modify skin.css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that and there are [no plans to change that](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4834#issuecomment-430610292).

Comment: In this case you would suggest to modify skin.css? i.e. by replacing like `body >` => `body > div >`

Comment: Yes, seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: The probem, that not only css, but js, jqueries rely on the structure like `body > elements`. The whole point to use templates, that it makes webprogramming faster, but to do those adjustments makes it way more difficult